# Python script doesn't delete file from archive -- printed command via terminal works fine

Tags: python, python-2.7, command, archive

I'm creating an archive in Python using this code:

```
#Creates archive using string like [proxy_16-08-15_08.57.07.tar]
proxyArchiveLabel = 'proxy_%s' % EXECUTION_START_TIME + '.tar'
log.info('Packaging %s ...' % proxyArchiveLabel)

#Removes .tar from label during creation
shutil.make_archive(proxyArchiveLabel.rsplit('.',1)[0], 'tar', verbose=True)
```

So this creates an archive fine in the local directory. The problem is, there's a specific directory in my archive I want to remove, due to it's size and lack of necessity for this task.

```
ExecWithLogging('tar -vf %s --delete ./roles/jobs/*' % proxyArchiveLabel)
# ------------
def ExecWithLogging(cmd):
    print cmd
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(' '), env=os.environ, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    while(True):
      log.info(p.stdout.readline().strip())
      if(p.poll() is not None):
        break
```

However, this seems to do basically nothing. The size remains the same. If I print `cmd` inside of the `ExecWithLogging`, and copy/past that command to a terminal in the working directory of the script, it works fine. Just to be sure, I also tried hard-coding the full path to where the archive is created as part of the `tar -vf %s --delete` command, but still nothing seemed to happen.

I do get this output in my INFO log: `tar: Pattern matching characters used in file names`, so I'm kind of thinking `Popen` is interpreting my command incorrectly somehow... (or rather, I'm more likely passing in something incorrectly).

Am I doing something wrong? What else can I try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to use the `--wildcards` option in the tar command, which enables pattern matching. This may well be what you are seeing in your log, be it somewhat cryptically.

Edit:
In answer to your question Why? I suspect that the shell is performing the wildcard expansion whilst the command proffered through Popen is not. The --wildcard option for tar, forces tar to perform the wildcard expansion.
For a more detailed explanation see here:
[Tar and wildcards](http://aplawrence.com/Linux/tar_wilcards.html)

Comment: Beautiful, this fixed it right out. Would be super interested in why the terminal didn't care, but passing it through `Popen` broke